Why did we include I/3 as part of our KCL equation although it's not passing through the 10 mA node?


Why did we include I/3 as part of our KCL equation although it's not passing through the 10mA node?

Why is the problem statement labeled 6.1 b and the correct answer key shows instead 6.1 c? Did you pull an answer from the wrong problem?

It is an illusion that there are 2 nodes in the top of the circuit. You can move both nodes much closer together. So close that they can‘t even be distinguished. That‘s why there is only one node on top which has 3 branches.
